# what is the equivalent function of matlab 'fix' in opencv?

Tags: opencv

What is the equivalent function of MATLAB [`fix()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fix.html) in OpenCV? I had searched on google for rounding off but I am unable to get the proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this in OpenCV with a single operation (as there is no C/C++ `std` math function that does this.)

You would need to do the equivalent of:

```
return (0 < n) ? std::floor(n) : std::ceil(n);
```

You can do this in OpenCV, by using `cv::compare(...,CMP_GT)` along with with `cv::ceil()` and `cv::floor()`.

C++11 added the equivalent function [`std::trunc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/trunc).

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution, in C++, cast to `int`, or `long`.

```
float x;
std::cout<< (int) x;
```

..if you can safely forget numbers that won't fit.

In case of an array (like Matlab's `fit`), try [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) or [`std::for_each`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) in conjunction with above.

EDIT: Also, GNU's [`libc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html) has `trunc()`, which some might find preferable.